# WPF popup control is closing immediately

Tags: wpf, popup

I am using the Pop up control in wpf. So, when the user clicks on some button the popup should get opened.
But in actual the popup open but closing immediately. I tried of using the StayOpen as true, but when using this though the main window is closed the popup is not getting closed.

here is my code:

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" StaysOpen="False" Placement="RelativePoint" materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth5" Style="{x:Null}">
                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="#d2d9d4" BorderThickness="0.6" ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Grid>
                        <ListView  MaxWidth="350" MaxHeight="450" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <!--Stuff-->
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
        </Popup>
```

And the code behind:

```
            Popup.PlacementTarget = sender as Button;
            Popup.IsOpen = true;
            //RPopup.StaysOpen = true; Making popup open even after the main window is closed by clink somewhere on screen.
            Popup.HorizontalOffset = ((Button)sender).ActualWidth + 10;
```

Is there anything I am missing, How to make popup to stay open until clicks on any other place?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. By default the PopUp stays open also by clicking somewhere else until `StaysOpen = false` is set. Do post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does it close after a few seconds or instantly?

Comment: I guess your code behind is 'button click event handler'.In first line, you cast sender as Button. but in last line you cast sender as Border. I think this is the problem

Comment: @Tronald, it closes instantly.

Comment: @ByoungSamMoon, Yeah, its a typo error, though It is a button the problem still exists.

Comment: @Rekshino, I can handle if user clicks somewhere on application window. If user clicks on some other places then how can I handle this.

like, I have opened chrome and my application. By default the application screen size is smaller means I will be allowed to click directly on chrome with out any click/touch on my application. In such a scenario if I opened the popup for which the staysOpen is set to true, though the main window of my application closes still the popup is stays on. If the staysOpen is false the popup closes instantly.

Comment: @sahithi As I wrote. I can't reproduce the issue. If `StaysOpen = false`, then all works as expected - click within WPF - App or outside (e.g. on Chrome-Browser) do close the pop up, till that moment popup stays open.

Comment: @Rekshino, I wonder why you are unable to reproduce. Anyway I just resolved it by replace moseleftbuttondown event with Mouseleftbuttonup for the button from which the popup comes. Thanks for the support :-)

Comment: @sahithi Maybe because something is different by me, therefore it is good to post an MCVE. Sometimes already by creating an MCVE the bug will be found or at least localized. So you speak about mouse event handler and I see no of them in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set StaysOpen to true.

Comment: if I set StaysOpen to true, if the main window is closed the popup is still not closed.